# Show saved password for ssh interpreter in PyCharm Professional

Tags: python, pycharm

I have created an ssh interpreter in PyCharm Professional and used a username and password for authentication. Now I forgot the password and want PyCharm to show it. Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: Check the keychain: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reference-ide-settings-password-safe.html

Comment: @kekec Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. Check if you have configured PyCharm to save passwords in a keychain. If is the case, you can access the password directly from the keychain. Does this solve the issue?

Comment: @kekec how can I access the keychain in ubunto?

Comment: May this help? https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-keyring/

Comment: @kekec thank you very much. Post the answer so I can award the bounty

Comment: @MarziHeidari There I posted the answer! Please accept the answer and award the bounty when possible! :) Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check [the keychain](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reference-ide-settings-password-safe.html), if you have configured PyCharm to save passwords there. If it is the case, you can access the password directly from the keychain. For Ubuntu, you may find more details [here](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-keyring/).

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem and solve it with kekec's answer.

I would like to describe it in detail.

1. check the keychain in pycharm.

> Settings/Preferences | Appearance and Behavior | System Settings | Passwords

2. if it's still default, using the keychain, you can open the GUI application *Password and Keys*, and find your forgotten password in *Logins*. But there are only user name and password, lacking of server name, I have to try.